# How to get a file, generated by Java code, with JavaScript and to upload it to the server in webview in Android 4.4

Tags: javascript, android, audio, file-upload

I want to implement an audio recorder with JavaScript in WebView in Android 4.4. My plan is to implement an API, with Java code, which can be called by JavaScript like: `Recorder.start` and `Recorder.end`.

For some reasons, I have to upload the generated audio file to the server by JavaScript, how can I get the file and upload it? Can Java implement an API which provides a `File object` that can be used by JavaScript directly?